# Can't export a NumPy array to R dataset

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2, scikit-image

I'm having some difficulties trying to convert a NumPy array to R data set. I have a 2D image of 2362 x 2163 on gray scale. I have to import the gray scale value of each pixel to do some statistical analysis. First, this is what I imported for  the process:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
from skimage import data
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from pandas import DataFrame
pandas2ri.activate()
```

First I import the image using cv2 as a NumPy array and just in case I converted the array to values between 0 and 255 (256 gray levels).

```py
xchest = cv2.imread("/home/user/xchest.tif", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
xchestsk = img_as_ubyte(xchest)
```

The output of:

```
type(xchestsk)
```

is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I visually checked the array an as expected is something like:

```
[[8, 8, 9, ... 200, 234, 245]...[250, 234, 134, ... 67, 8, 8]]
```

I need all that pixel information on a simple data set that I can use and analyze on RStudio. I tried with:

```py
xchest_R = DataFrame(xchestsk)
xchest_R = r.data('xchestsk')
r.assign("test", xchest_R)
r("save(test, file='/home/user/xchest.gzip', compress=TRUE)")
```

But when I load it on R:

```
> load("/home/user/xchest.gzip")
```

I just get a value: `test > "xchestsk"`
Like if I just imported a string.

I tried with:

```
np.save("/home/user/xchest.npy", xchestsk)
```

But when I try to import it on R with:

```
> library(RcppCNPy)
> xchest_R <- npyLoad("/home/user/xchest.npy", "integer")
```

RStudio crashes and I have to restart the session.

Finally, I tried converting the NumPy array to a CSV file:

```
np.savetxt("/home/eera5607/xchest.csv", xchestsk, delimiter=",")
```

But when I import it to R:

```
> xchest_data = read.csv(file="/home/eera5607/xchest.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

I can't do simple statistical analysis like:

```
> mean(xchest_data)
```

Because I get this warning:

```
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I tried converting the data to one variable and 5000000+ points with:

```py
xchest_list = xchestsk.tolist()
xchest_ov = []
for list in xchest_list:
    xchest_ov += list
```

Then I converted the `xchest_ov` list to CSV but I get the same warning in RStudio.

What I need is to import all those values, if possible, keeping the matrix structure (but it is not necessary, at least import the pixel values as a regular R data set) to which I can apply some statistical analysis. I know I can do some analysis directly on Python but I would like this data on RStudio. I have very little knowledge in this topics. I'm a radiologist and this is the first time I'm working with R.

Comment: Not familiar with `RcppCNPy`, but the csv method should work. What happens in that method when you call `str(xchest_data)`? I would not expect `mean` to work directly on the data frame, in R `mean` does not have a method for data frames or matrices, it mostly accepts vector input only. You can still do other statistical analysis but if you have specific questions ask there. To clarify, data.frames in R are analogous to pandas DataFrames, matrices and arrays are more similar to NumPy arrays.

Comment: @CalumYou thanks, the output of `str(xchest_data)` is: `'data.frame': 2163 obs. of  2362 variables:
 $ V1   : num  8 8 8 8 8 13 23 36 38 34 ...
 $ V2   : num  8 8 8 10 8 15 20 23 36 34 ...
 $ V3   : num  8 8 8 11 8 15 21 24 36 35 ...
 $ V4   : num  8 8 8 11 8 17 21 27 37 35 ...
 $ V5   : num  8 8 8 11 8 16 21 26 40 39 ...
 $ V6   : num  8 8 8 12 8 14 20 26 39 35 ...
 $ V7   : num  8 8 8 12 8 17 18 31 41 42 ...
 $ V8   : num  8 8 8 12 8 17 23 32 40 39 ...
 $ V9   : num  8 8 8 12 8 14 23 29 39 39 ...
 $ V10  : num  8 8 8 12 8 16 23 25 37 36 ...` and continues until is truncated.

Comment: Ok, then looks like the data has been read into a data frame successfully. Is there still an issue?

Comment: @CalumYou yes, how do I work with all the data points as a whole if I have 2362 variables (the image height)? I wanted like to have a clean set of data points to which I can apply even simple statistic analysis. For example, can do `x = xchest_data$V99` and do `mean(x)` and that works, but at this point I don't need that because that is only one row of the image.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like `x = xchest_data$V1-V99` as an example?

Comment: If you want to convert your data into a vector that just stacks columns, you can do `as.vector(as.matrix(x_chest_data))`. You can call `mean()` on the result of this. But I suggest that you resubmit with more specific questions as you get to them.